# com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCSQLSyntaxErrorException: An undefined column name was detected

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I couldn't find why I am getting this exception. Please help me to find it.
I am using the IBM DB2/AS400 DB engine. I have checked the column names in the database with the names I declared in the java class. They are the same. After this exception, the app is not stopping but it's continued further. somewhere in the app, I am trying to save using the repository (repository.save(dailyErrorVO);) and there it's waiting for a long time and going into some deadlock.

```
public interface DailyErrorRepository
    extends JpaRepository<DailyErrorVO, String>, CrudRepository<DailyErrorVO, String> {

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_DAILY_ERROR")
public class DailyErrorVO implements Comparable<DailyErrorVO>, Cloneable, Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4917078316183458138L;

private Date EFF_DATE; 
private String ERRCODE; 
private String ERROR_MESSAGE;
private String EXCEPTION_MESSAGE;
private String EXTRNL_POI;
private String IMPACT_AREA; 

@Column(name="LAST_MOD_TIME_DT", nullable = false)
private Timestamp LAST_MOD_TIME_DT; 

@Id
@Column(nullable = true)
private String MEMBER_ID;
private String PAY_SEQ; 
private String PROG_ID;

@Column(name="PROGRAM", nullable = false)
private String PROGRAM = CommonProperties.PROGRAM_NAME;

@Column(name="RUN_DATE", nullable = false)
private Date RUN_DATE;
private String SQLCODE; 
private String SSN;     
private String TABLE_NM;
public Date getEFF_DATE() {
    return EFF_DATE;
}
public void setEFF_DATE(Date eFF_DATE) {
    EFF_DATE = eFF_DATE;
}
public String getERRCODE() {
    return ERRCODE;
}
public void setERRCODE(String eRRCODE) {
    ERRCODE = eRRCODE;
}
public String getERROR_MESSAGE() {
    return ERROR_MESSAGE;
}
public void setERROR_MESSAGE(String eRROR_MESSAGE) {
    ERROR_MESSAGE = eRROR_MESSAGE;
}
public String getEXCEPTION_MESSAGE() {
    return EXCEPTION_MESSAGE;
}
public void setEXCEPTION_MESSAGE(String eXCEPTION_MESSAGE) {
    EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = eXCEPTION_MESSAGE;
}
public String getEXTRNL_POI() {
    return EXTRNL_POI;
}
public void setEXTRNL_POI(String eXTRNL_POI) {
    EXTRNL_POI = eXTRNL_POI;
}
public String getIMPACT_AREA() {
    return IMPACT_AREA;
}
public void setIMPACT_AREA(String iMPACT_AREA) {
    IMPACT_AREA = iMPACT_AREA;
}
public Timestamp getLAST_MOD_TIME_DT() {
    return LAST_MOD_TIME_DT;
}
public void setLAST_MOD_TIME_DT(Timestamp lAST_MOD_TIME_DT) {
    LAST_MOD_TIME_DT = lAST_MOD_TIME_DT;
}
public String getMEMBER_ID() {
    return MEMBER_ID;
}
public void setMEMBER_ID(String mEMBER_ID) {
    MEMBER_ID = mEMBER_ID;
}
public String getPAY_SEQ() {
    return PAY_SEQ;
}
public void setPAY_SEQ(String pAY_SEQ) {
    PAY_SEQ = pAY_SEQ;
}
public String getPROG_ID() {
    return PROG_ID;
}
public void setPROG_ID(String pROG_ID) {
    PROG_ID = pROG_ID;
}
public String getPROGRAM() {
    return PROGRAM;
}
public void setPROGRAM(String pROGRAM) {
    PROGRAM = pROGRAM;
}
public Date getRUN_DATE() {
    return RUN_DATE;
}
public void setRUN_DATE(Date rUN_DATE) {
    RUN_DATE = rUN_DATE;
}
public String getSQLCODE() {
    return SQLCODE;
}
public void setSQLCODE(String sQLCODE) {
    SQLCODE = sQLCODE;
}
public String getSSN() {
    return SSN;
}
public void setSSN(String sSN) {
    SSN = sSN;
}
public String getTABLE_NM() {
    return TABLE_NM;
}
public void setTABLE_NM(String tABLE_NM) {
    TABLE_NM = tABLE_NM;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TDailyErrorVO [EFF_DATE=" + EFF_DATE + ", ERRCODE=" + ERRCODE + ", ERROR_MESSAGE=" + ERROR_MESSAGE
            + ", EXCEPTION_MESSAGE=" + EXCEPTION_MESSAGE + ", EXTRNL_POI=" + EXTRNL_POI + ", IMPACT_AREA="
            + IMPACT_AREA + ", LAST_MOD_TIME_DT=" + LAST_MOD_TIME_DT + ", MEMBER_ID=" + MEMBER_ID + ", PAY_SEQ="
            + PAY_SEQ + ", PROG_ID=" + PROG_ID + ", PROGRAM=" + PROGRAM + ", RUN_DATE=" + RUN_DATE + ", SQLCODE="
            + SQLCODE + ", SSN=" + SSN + ", TABLE_NM=" + TABLE_NM + "]";
}

@Override
public int compareTo(DailyErrorVO o) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCSQLSyntaxErrorException: An undefined column name was detected.
at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.createSQLExceptionSubClass(JDError.java:897) ~[jt400-jdk8-9.5.jar:JTOpen 9.5]
at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:421) ~[jt400-jdk8-9.5.jar:JTOpen 9.5]
at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:397) ~[jt400-jdk8-9.5.jar:JTOpen 9.5]
at com.ibm.as400.access.JDServerRow.findField(JDServerRow.java:519) ~[jt400-jdk8-9.5.jar:JTOpen 9.5]
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.findColumn(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:575) ~[jt400-jdk8-9.5.jar:JTOpen 9.5]
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.getString(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:3424) ~[jt400-jdk8-9.5.jar:JTOpen 9.5]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getString(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:?]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.resultSetSchemaName(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.sequenceInformationList(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:403) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:268) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) [hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) [spring-orm-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) [spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) [spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) [spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) [spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) [spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$148/0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) [spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) [spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) [spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) [spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) [spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) [spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) [spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
at com.benefeds.batch.ABWReversalFileValidationStarter.main(ABWReversalFileValidationStarter.java:9) [classes/:?]
```

Comment: Where is T_TIME_RELEASE come from? I can't see it anywhere in your code

Comment: T_TIME_RELEASE is another table. I was trying to fetch run_date from that table on startup. I commented those two lines tried. still getting the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to the stack trace that you posted, Hibernate is unable to determine the current value of some sequence which happens at boot time. Maybe you configured the wrong dialect or the dialect has a bug. Please share the dialect that you use and the Hibernate version, as well as the exact database name and version. Chances are, you can simply subclass a dialect and fix the bug yourself.